# Flutter Tabbar Customization

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make UI like this:

[image: Tabbar]

Please give me some suggestion how can I edit TabBar for result like this.

Code I tried:

```
ListView(
                                children: [
                                  TabBar(
                                    controller: tabController,
                                    indicator: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                          topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                                          topRight: Radius.circular(8.0)),
                                      border: Border(
                                        top: borderSide,
                                        left: borderSide,
                                        right: borderSide,
                                        bottom: borderSide.copyWith(width: 0.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    tabs: [
                                      Tab(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Nearby',
                                          style:
                                              textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                                            color: primaryRedColor,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeightManager.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Tab(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Popular',
                                          style:
                                              textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                                            color: primaryRedColor,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeightManager.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Tab(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'New',
                                          style:
                                              textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                                            color: primaryRedColor,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeightManager.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                        0.3,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(8.0)),
                                      border: Border(
                                        top: borderSide,
                                        left: borderSide,
                                        right: borderSide,
                                        bottom: borderSide,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: TabBarView(
                                      controller: tabController,
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          color: bgColor,
                                          child: const Center(
                                            child: Text('Tab 1'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          color: bgColor,
                                          child: const Center(
                                            child: Text('Tab 2'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          color: bgColor,
                                          child: const Center(
                                            child: Text('Tab 3'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
```

This is what result it got:

[image: My Tabbar]

Please provide me with some suggestions on how to customize the TabBar to achieve a design like this. Currently, my main objective is to eliminate the border located beneath the tab. Can you guide me on how to accomplish this task?"

Comment: please show some code samples of what you tried so far and ask more specific questions

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
child: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 49,
        left: 10.0,
        right: 10.0,
      ),
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller.animation,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          return Transform.rotate(
            angle: 0,
            child: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                width: double.maxFinite,
                child: Text(
                    "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium"),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                width: double.maxFinite,
                child: Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco"),
              )
            ][_controller.animation.value.round()],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 10.0,
            right: 10.0,
          ),
          width: 200,
          height: 50,
          child: TabBar(
              controller: _controller,
              labelColor: Colors.black,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                  right: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                  top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text("Apple"),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text("Android"),
                  ),
                )
              ]),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Use this snippets you have achieve your goal.